# What is the difference between “Of”, “Of the”, “the Of the” and “the Of ”?

Tags: articles

I am learning English from the book and I read the sentence that make me very confuse.
The sentence is "I have no memory of the moment of impact." I can't really understand this meaning.

What is the difference

> Memory of impact
> Memory of the impact
> The memory of impact
> The memory of the impact

Another examples

> king of fighters
> king of the fighters
> The king of fighters
> The king of the fighters

What is the difference between this sentences? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

*The moment of impact* is the moment when something hit something else (perhaps a car accident). The speaker cannot remember that moment (they have *no memory* of it).

Because *no* (not any) comes before *memory*, there is no need for the definite article *the.* If the person did remember something, they might say "The memory of the impact will stay with me for a long time."

A *king of fighters* could mean an especially good fighter (one who is special among fighters in general). A *king of the fighters* might be the leader of a particular group of fighters.